# electron-rebuild - Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, electron-rebuild

I found many threads regarding this issue, But none of them worked for me

Enviroment:

- Windows 10
- Node v14.18.0
- "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7"

I try run the command `.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`
And get this output (I replaced the working dir with **...**):

```
An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
node-gyp failed to rebuild '...\node_modules\pkcs11js'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use



Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild '...\node_modules\pkcs11js'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use


    at NodeGyp.rebuildModule (...\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-type\node-gyp.js:117:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuildNodeGypModule (...\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:94:9)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuild (...\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:124:14)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuildModuleAt (...\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:145:13)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuild (...\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:108:17)
    at async ...\node_modules\electron-rebuild\lib\src\cli.js:154:9
```

I tried the following:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2017
npm config set msvs_version 2019
npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

When trying to install build tools globally using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` 
Its stays stuck like this (Waited for more then 90 minutes before terminating it):

```
Starting installation...
Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
This will likely take some time - please be patient!

Status from the installers:
---------- Visual Studio Build Tools ----------
Still waiting for installer log file...
------------------- Python --------------------
Successfully installed Python 2.7
```

Also tried configure node-gyp like this (even though its global configuration and running electron-build inside repository used local node-gyp):

```
PS ...> node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2019
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
gyp info using node@14.18.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Python310\python.exe"
gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.31911.196) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Python310\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '...\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.18.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.18.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\14.18.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=...',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   '...\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: ...) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:261:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--msvs_version=2019"
gyp ERR! cwd ...
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

What am I missing? Been trying to fix it for hours